# Configure Openfire server to support GCM push notification

Tags: java, google-cloud-messaging, openfire

I'm writing an Android chat application right now using Openfire as the xmpp server. The problem is that if I use the Xmpp server for push notification, it is fine for when user is online but it has some issues when user is offline. So is there a way to configure Openfire to let GCM to host the push notification? Is the re such thing as a GCM plugin for Openfire?

Answer (score 0):

We have build an application with almost similar conditions like yours. However, for sending push to offline users we send it through server side.

In your implementation while sending message you can check if the user is offline then you can hit your server api to send push. (Also you can implement the GCM on client side too only you have to know its deviceToken or the GCM id)

XMPP manages the offline messages. So you need to handle only the pushnotification part and need not worry about saving the message.

Comment: you did a great job, can you please refer any example code regarding this that will be greatful.